# List in a quote environment that not goes out of the space reserved to it

Tags: spacing, lists, itemize

As you can see in the image attached my problem is about to list "Istanza" and "Domanda" with a sort of emphasis, so I put them in quote environment but the entry for "Domanda" goes out a little of the space reserved for text, how can I fit it in optimal way?

[image]

This is the code:

```
\begin{quote}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item[Istanza:] Insieme finito $ U $ di oggetti, una taglia $ s(u) \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \: \forall u \in U $, una capacità intera
                        per i bins $ B $ e un intero positivo $ K $.
        \item[Domanda:] Esiste una partizione di $ U $ in insiemi disgiunti $ U_1, U_2, ..., U_k $ tale che la somma delle taglie degli
                        oggetti in ogni $ U_i $ è $ \leq B $.
    \end{itemize}
\end{quote}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Try loading `enumitem` and using `\begin{itemize}[align=left]`

Comment: You could use a description environment, but the hanging indentation would not match the word length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with tabularx.  The hard part was putting a blank line between the definitions.

Using the array package one can make the bold face automatic.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]% needed for \hrule
\hrule
\begin{quote}
    \begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\rightskip}{@{} rX @{}}
        \textbf{Istanza:} & Insieme finito $ U $ di oggetti, una taglia $ s(u) \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \: \forall u \in U $, una capacità intera
                        per i bins $ B $ e un intero positivo $ K $. \\
        \\% add blank line between rows
        \textbf{Domanda:} & Esiste una partizione di $ U $ in insiemi disgiunti $ U_1, U_2, ..., U_k $ tale che la somma delle taglie degli
                        oggetti in ogni $ U_i $ è $ \leq B $.
    \end{tabularx}
\end{quote}
\hrule
\begin{quote}\def\arraystretch{2}\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}% add space between rows
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} rX @{}}
        \textbf{Istanza:} & Insieme finito $ U $ di oggetti, una taglia $ s(u) \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \: \forall u \in U $, una capacità intera
                        per i bins $ B $ e un intero positivo $ K $. \\
        \textbf{Domanda:} & Esiste una partizione di $ U $ in insiemi disgiunti $ U_1, U_2, ..., U_k $ tale che la somma delle taglie degli
                        oggetti in ogni $ U_i $ è $ \leq B $.
    \end{tabularx}
    \vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}%
\end{quote}
\hrule

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want, but is possible to decrease the space between the two entries of tabularx?

Comment: Try `\def\arraystretch{1.5}` and adjust or remove the `\vspace` for the start and end gaps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `enumitem` and `calc`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]

\begin{quote}
    \begin{itemize}[align = left, labelwidth=\widthof{Domanda\hskip\labelsep}]
        \item[Istanza:] Insieme finito $ U $ di oggetti, una taglia $ s(u) \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \: \forall u \in U $, una capacità intera
                        per i bins $ B $ e un intero positivo $ K $.
        \item[Domanda:] Esiste una partizione di $ U $ in insiemi disgiunti $ U_1, U_2, ..., U_k $ tale che la somma delle taglie degli
                        oggetti in ogni $ U_i $ è $ \leq B $.
    \end{itemize}
\end{quote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But now they are both out of the space reserved to text